# Run two unit test projects using github action in .Net /.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, github, .net-core, github-actions

I have two Unit test Projects. On the github action, I want to run them one after the other. Here is the code I have written, but it only runs one test project.

```
name: Build and Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: [windows-latest]

    env:
      Solution_Name: "Skeleton.sln"
      Test_Project_Path: Tests\Test.csproj
      
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0

    # Install the .NET Core workload
    - name: Install .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x

    # Add  MSBuild to the PATH: https://github.com/microsoft/setup-msbuild
    - name: Setup MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2
    
    #restoring the nuget dependencies
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: nuget restore "Skeleton.sln"

    #build solution
    - name: Build Solution
      run: msbuild "Skeleton.sln"
      
    # Execute all unit tests in the solution
    - name: Execute unit tests
      run: dotnet test
```

I have another test project at the path "UnitTest/UnitTest.csproj"

How do I run this after running "Test/Test.csproj"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test

Comment: you can pass the test project path to the `dotnet test` command. Please the documentations from the above link and see the examples given in it.